# can someone explain this short segment of C++ code, I can't make heads or tails of it

Tags: c++, function, pointers, syntax

```
#include <opcodes.h>
const char *getOpcodeName(
    uint8_t op
)
{
    #define OPCODE(x, y) if((0x##y)==op) return "OP_" #x;
        OPCODES
    #undef OPCODE
    return "OP_UNKNOWN";
}
```

Link to the code here: https://github.com/znort987/blockparser/blob/master/opcodes.cpp

Here is a link to the included [opcodes.h](https://github.com/znort987/blockparser/blob/master/opcodes.h)

I understand this is just a strangely formatted function, however, I am wondering what exactly the `*` at the beginning of the function name means. I assume it has something to do with pointers?

Also, how are the `#undef` and `#define` statements valid? There's no semicolon after either one, and one of them seems to be defined as a one-line function. What does `(0x##y)` mean? What does `return "OP_" #x` mean? I haven't ever come across syntax like this before.

I want to get into C++ more seriously, but it's very hard when looking at code to tell what exactly is going on. How can I learn the syntax and rules most effectively?

Comment: the function returns a string. That's what the `const char*` means. In this case they're string literals.

Comment: Look up what a *macro* is in C or C++.

Comment: String concatenation needs a `+` sign I thought? How does `return "OP_" #x;` return a string?

Comment: That's for `std::string`. `#` in this case is for the preprocessor. So `OPCODE("foo", 1234)` turns into `if((0x1234==op) return "OP_foo"`

Comment: @bvpx String *literals* are concatenated if they follow immediately after one another - `"abc_" "def"` becomes `"abc_def"` during compilation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run your code thru a [C++ preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor), e.g. using `g++ -Wall -C -E opcodes.cpp > opcodes.i` then look inside the generated `opcodes.i`

`#define` is not a statement but a [preprocessor directive](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/).

The macro `OPCODES` gets expanded to some big chunk, notably containing `OPCODE( NOP, 61)` which would get expanded to something like

```
if ((0x61)==op) return "OP_" "NOP";
```

The two string literals are concatenated into one, `"OP_NOP"` here.

GCC has a good documentation on its [cpp preprocessor](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/). Read about [stringification](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html) (with the single `#` like the ending `#x;` of the `OPCODE` macro) and about [concatenation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html) (with a double `##` like `(0x##y)` of the `OPCODE` macro).

Comment: Is this essentially an advanced way of writing a function that otherwise would have 100 `if` statements?

Comment: Yes, but I would not call that "advanced way"

Comment: What would you call it then :)? By the way, I still don't understand what `0x##y` means exactly.

Comment: I just added two chapter references to GCC cpp documentation.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** This function converts opcodes to string.

The `*` IS RELATED to do with pointers! in fact, this function returns a `const char *` type. This is a pointer for a char buffer (in this case) used to point to a [C-String](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string). Every C-String is actually a buffer with "readable characteres" (alphanumerical, some accents, basic symbols + some stuff) followed by a byte of value 0 (or `'\0'`) to indicate the end of the string!

This function converts opcodes (assembly instructions) to a readable string. So The intention of the programmer was to transform:

- 0x01 -> OP_CODE1
- 0x02 -> OP_CODE2
- 0x03 -> OP_CODE3

The expanded version of the code is something like this:

```
const char *getOpcodeName( uint8_t op )
{
    if((0x01)==op) return "OP_X";
    if((0x02)==op) return "OP_Y";
    if((0x03)==op) return "OP_Z";
    ...
    if((0x??)==op) return "OP_?";
    return "OP_UNKNOWN";
}
```

Insted of write houndreds of IF's ... the programmer decided to create the macro

```
#define OPCODE(x, y) if((0x##y)==op) return "OP_" #x;
```

So it's possible to write the OPCODES table easily like this:

```
#define OPCODES \
OPCODE( 01, "X" ) \
OPCODE( 02, "Y" ) \
OPCODE( 03, "Z" ) \
...
OPCODE( ??, "?" )
```

Opcodes are codes that indentify the processor instruction (assembly instructions). Example of  real instructions (for some [Intel processor](http://sparksandflames.com/files/x86InstructionChart.html)) are:

```
  inc eax      ; opcode = 0x40
  pusha        ; opcode = 0x60
  nop          ; opcode = 0x90
```

So your table could be:

```
#define OPCODES \
OPCODE( 40, "INCEAX" ) \
OPCODE( 60, "PUSHA" ) \
OPCODE( 90, "NOP" )
```