# Enum and strings

Tags: c, string, enums

```
int main()
{     
    enum a {cat, dog, elephant};
    enum a b;

    b=dog;
    if (b==dog) printf("Y"); else printf("N");

    return 0;
}
```

The program above works. It shows `Y`. But I do not see it very useful, so I want to make something similar, but with strings:

```
int main()
{     
    enum a {cat, dog, elephant};
    enum a b;

    char s[100];
    gets(s);

    b=dog;
    if (b==s) printf("Y"); else printf("N");

    return 0;
}
```

Even if `s=="dog"`, It doesn't work.

Comment: Shall that be C or C++?

Comment: `<br>` works in C++?

Comment: No.. Ignore those <br>. And It should be in C.

Comment: It won't compile because you compare a char array to an enum.

Comment: I deleted those <br>. They were from html code.

Comment: enum are integer, in order to convert the string to the enum you need to parse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following approach

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum Animal { cat, dog, elephant };
    char * animal_name[] = { "cat", "dog", "elephant" };
    enum Animal b;
    size_t n;

    char s[100];
    fgets( s , sizeof( s ), stdin );

    n = strlen( s );
    if ( s[n - 1] == '\n' ) s[n - 1] = '\0';

    b = dog;
    if ( strcmp( animal_name[b], s ) == 0 ) printf( "Y\n" ); 
    else printf( "N\n" );

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter `dog` then the output is

```
Y
```

Also before comparing strings you could convert the entered string to the lower case that is used in strings of the array of animal names.

Or you could use C# instead of C where enumerators can be converted to strings. :)

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because you are comparing enum to a pointer.

While `char s[100]` can indeed hold a string, `s` simply points to a memory location of the start of your string. In other words, `s` is a memory chunk, 100 bytes long.

Comment: I know what is the problem. But I do no know how to create a program with those functions. enum a {"cat", "dog", "elephant"}; do not work with "".

Comment: @Abbey: First answer Deduplicator's question: Should the program be C or C++? The solutions will be different.

Comment: @MOehm , I've removed the [tag:c++] tag from the question as OP mentions "It should be in C" in [one of his comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27702564/enum-and-strings#comment43817575_27702564)

Answer (score 0):

You could play [C preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) tricks notably with [X-macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) (see e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19217972/841108)).

You could have a macro invoking some macro `P` on each animal

```
#define DO_ANIMALS(P) \
  P(cat) \
  P(dog) \
  P(elephant)
```

then use it to declare the `enum`

```
enum animals_en {
#define DECLARE_ANIMAL(An) En,
DO_ANIMALS(DECLARE_ANIMAL)
};
```

and later use it to convert a string `s` to the `enum animals_en`

```
enum animals_en convert_string_to_animal(const char*s) {
#define CHECK_STRING_ANIMAL(An) if (!strcmp(s, #An)) return An;
DO_ANIMALS(CHECK_STRING_ANIMAL)
   fprintf(stderr, "bad animal %s\n", s); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

<sup>You may want to look at the preprocessed form obtained with `gcc -Wall -C -E yoursource.c > yoursource.i` then use some editor or pager on the generated `yoursource.i` to understand more how that works.</sup>

Read documentation of [GNU cpp](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/), notably [stringification](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html) & [concatenation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html).

You could also improve this code to generate something similar to [the answer from Vlad from Moscow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27702773/841108).

Such tricks would work both in C and in C++, but are more C-like. (In C++11 you would rather try having templates).